# Проблемы с jquery скриптом в wordpress

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

Вот так подключаю js и css

```
    function bankadata_include_js() {
      wp_enqueue_script( 'myscript1', 'assets/js/main_slider.js', array('jquery') );
      wp_enqueue_script( 'myscript2', 'assets/js/second_slider.js', array('jquery') );
    }
    function bankadata_include_css() {
      wp_enqueue_style('my-styles-1', plugins_url("assets/css/style.css", __FILE__));
      wp_enqueue_style('my-styles', "https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css");
    }
    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','bankadata_include_js');
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','bankadata_include_css');
```

Сам код слайдера

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('.tabs_menu a').click(function(e){
          e.preventDefault();
          $('.tabs_menu .active').removeClass('active');
          $(this).addClass('active');
          var tab = $(this).attr('href');
          $('.tab').not(tab).css({'display':'none'});
          $(tab).fadeIn(400);
        });
      });
```

Сам скрипт, без вставки в wp плагин работает как нужно.CSS и HTML код pastebin.com/VQXi8FZy

Comment: В чем проблема-то? Что хотите сделать, что не получается? Ошибка какая-то в консоли? Телепаты сюда иногда заглядывают, но не оч часто.

Comment: Просто не изменяются слайды. CSS и HTML код http://pastebin.com/VQXi8FZy
Предположений почему не работает  - нету, ибо без интеграции в WP все ок.

Comment: Ок, выглядит действительно как какая-то специфическая вордпресс-проблема, а я с вордпрессом в жизни не работал. Сначала локализуем проблему. Проверьте в первую очередь, добавляется ли скрипт в html, загенеренный движком (проблема в том, что не так отрабатывает), или не добавляется вообще (не подключается).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Скорее всего проблема вот в этом подключении скриптов

```
function bankadata_include_js() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'myscript1', 'assets/js/main_slider.js', array('jquery') );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'myscript2', 'assets/js/second_slider.js', array('jquery') );
}
```

Вторым аргументом для функции `wp_enqueue_script()` вы указываете относительный путь. В итоге путь к вашему скрипту будет иметь вид `http://your_site.comassets/js/main_slider.js`, что явно является ошибкой уже потому, что отсутствует слэш после домена первого уровня. Если папка со скриптами находится в папке вашего плагина, используйте функцию `plugins_url()` для формирования правильного `url`, либо поставьте слэш перед `assets`, если эта дирректория лежит в корне сайта. То есть либо

```
wp_enqueue_script('myscript1', plugins_url('assets/js/main_slider.js', __FILE__), array('jquery'));
```

либо

```
wp_enqueue_script('myscript1', '/assets/js/main_slider.js', array('jquery'));
```

Comment: "В итоге путь к вашему скрипту будет иметь вид http://your_site.comassets/js/main_slider.js" - меня вот эта строчка немного смущает. Я с вордпрессом в жизни не работал, но неужели он действительно склеит такой путь? Я бы ожидал, что он поймет строчку без начального слеша как relative path относительно чего-то и будет что-то типа "relative root"/assets/js/main_slider.js; Хотя может быть он и правда настолько туп, мало ли

Comment: Ну не то чтобы туп, просто он так работает) и да, именно так и склеит, проверено не единожды